# Find the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\Bbb Q$ be the group of rationals under addition and let $\Bbb Q^*$ be the group of non-zero rational numbers under multiplication.Find the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$ and the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Q^*$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Attempt**:

Consider $\Bbb Q^*$ ,let the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Q^*$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$ be denoted by $\langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle=A$.

$\frac{1}{2}\in \langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle\implies 2 \in A\implies \frac{1}{2^n} ,2^n\in A$ and since $1\in A$ so

**$\langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle=\{\frac{1}{2^n},2^n,1;n\in \Bbb N\}$**.

**For $(\Bbb Q,+)$**,

$0\in A,2\times \frac{1}{2}=1\in A,-1\in A$ and hence $\Bbb Z\subset A$ .

Also $\frac{n}{2}\in A$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ and hence $\frac{-n}{2}\in A$.

But I can't figure out what will be  $\langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of $\mathbb{Q}^*$, your answer doesn't make sense. What is $n$?. The answer is$$\left\langle\frac12\right\rangle=\left\{2^n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

In the case of $\mathbb Q$, you nearly made it. The answer is$$\left\langle\frac12\right\rangle=\left\{\frac n2\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

Comment: you have not included identity in the first case

Comment: @Maths_Student $2^0=1$.

Comment: okay thank you very much

Comment: *A side remark (and an exercise (!)):* Let $G$ be a group and $x\in G$, then the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $x$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.